How to implement conditional Rate Limit in Loopback4?
How to implement conditional Rate Limit in Loopback4?
I am trying to implement a Rate Limit functionality in Loopback4, which is controlled by a condition specified in the controller method metadata.
Here is an example of my code:
Rate Limit Check Function:
import { Context } from '@loopback/core';
import { MetadataInspector } from '@loopback/metadata';
import { HttpErrors, RestBindings } from '@loopback/rest';

import { RateLimitMetadata } from '../decorators/rate-limit.decorator';

const requestCounts = new Map<string, { count: number; timestamp: number }>();

export async function rateLimitMiddleware(ctx: Context) {
  const requestContext: Context = await ctx.get(RestBindings.Http.CONTEXT);
  const route = requestContext.getSync(RestBindings.Operation.ROUTE);

  const controllerClass = route.spec['x-controller-class'];
  const controllerMethodName = route.spec['x-operation-name'];

  const methodMetadata = MetadataInspector.getMethodMetadata<RateLimitMetadata>(
    'rateLimit',
    controllerClass.prototype,
    controllerMethodName,
  );

  if (methodMetadata != null) {
    const { maxRequests, windowMinutes, condition } = methodMetadata;

    if (condition != null && !condition(ctx)) {
      return;
    }

    const windowMs = windowMinutes * 60 * 1000;
    const clientIp = ctx.request.ip;
    const endpoint = `${ctx.request.method} ${ctx.request.path}`;
    const key = `${clientIp}:${endpoint}`;

    const now = Date.now();
    const requestInfo = requestCounts.get(key);

    if (requestInfo == null) {
      requestCounts.set(key, { count: 1, timestamp: now });
    } else {
      if (now - requestInfo.timestamp < windowMs) {
        if (requestInfo.count >= maxRequests) {
          throw new HttpErrors.TooManyRequests(`Rate limit exceeded. Try again in ${windowMinutes} minute(s).`);
        } else {
          requestInfo.count++;
        }
      } else {
        requestCounts.set(key, { count: 1, timestamp: now });
      }
    }
  }
}

Sequence Class:
export class Sequence extends MiddlewareSequence {
  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    await rateLimitMiddleware(context, async () => {
      await super.handle(context);
    });
  }
}

Registering the new Sequence in the application:
import { Sequence } from './sequence';

export class MyApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super(options);

    this.sequence(Sequence);

    // ...
  }
}

Decorator Code
import { MetadataInspector } from '@loopback/metadata';
import { MethodDecoratorFactory } from '@loopback/core';
import { MiddlewareContext } from "@loopback/rest";

export interface RateLimitMetadata {
  maxRequests: number;
  windowMinutes: number;
  condition?: (ctx: MiddlewareContext) => boolean;
}

export function RateLimit(maxRequests: number, windowMinutes: number, condition?: (ctx: MiddlewareContext) => boolean) {
  return MethodDecoratorFactory.createDecorator<RateLimitMetadata>(
    'rateLimit',
    {
      maxRequests,
      windowMinutes,
      condition
    },
  );
}

However, I am encountering the following error:
Request GET / failed with status code 500. ResolutionError: The key 'rest.operation.route' is not bound to any value in context RequestContext-KAUQzJReRX2ik839qZBuBg-3 (context: RequestContext-KAUQzJReRX2ik839qZBuBg-3, binding: rest.operation.route)

Interestingly, when I log the context in the Sequence, it prints the context object, but when I log the passed context in rateLimitMiddleware, nothing is printed.
How to properly implement conditional Rate Limit in Loopback4? I would appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this issue.
I tried implementing a rate limit functionality in Loopback4 using a middleware function that checks request metadata for rate limiting conditions. I integrated this middleware into the application's request handling sequence. I expected the middleware to limit the number of requests based on specified conditions. However, I encountered a ResolutionError stating that the key 'rest.operation.route' is not bound in the request context. Interestingly, logging the context in the sequence shows it correctly, but logging it inside the middleware shows nothing. I need help to correctly implement this rate limiting functionality.
